# c# code to c++(memory maped file)

Tags: c#, c++

this is method from my c# application.
I need translate this code to c++

```
MemoryMappedFile myNonPersisterMemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("myNonPersisterMemoryMappedFile", 10000000);
public static void send_data(byte[] b)
    {

        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b.Length.ToString());
        byte[] f = new byte[b.Length + 1 + bytes.Length];
        f[0] = (byte)bytes.Length;
        Array.Copy(bytes, 0, f, 1, bytes.Length);
        Array.Copy(b, 0, f, 1 + bytes.Length, b.Length);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(myNonPersisterMemoryMappedFile.CreateViewStream(0, 10000000));
        bw.Write(f, 0, f.Length);
        bw.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a language translation service. Have you tried converting it yourself? Where are you stuck? Is there any line in particularly that is confusing you?

Comment: I cannot do var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b.Length.ToString());

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047673/transfering-data-through-a-memory-mapped-file-using-win32-winapi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A direct transliteration from one language to another is a *bad idea*.

Instead:

1. Find out what the code does and formulate its contract.
2. Design the proper interface in the target language.
3. Implement it in the target language.

Do so, and come back if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
System::String^ str = rgbValues->Length.ToString();
array<Byte>^ one =System::Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(str);
array<Byte>^ all = gcnew array<Byte>(one->Length + 1 + rgbValues->Length);
all[0] = one->Length;
System::Array::Copy(one, 0, all, 1, one->Length);
System::Array::Copy(rgbValues, 0, all, (1 + one->Length), rgbValues->Length);
```

Comment: That's not C++ but C++/CLI, a different language.